# Are annotations applicable to subclasses?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, inheritance, annotations

I've wondered this for a while, but haven't been able to find anything on the topic.

Let's say I'm using Spring MVC and defining a series of `Controller`s.

```
@RestController
public abstract class AbstractController {

    @Resource
    private Environment env;

    ...
    ...
}
```

For the following, is a `@RestController` annotation necessary for `UserController` to register?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user")
public class UserController extends AbstractController {

    @RequestMapping("value = "", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<User> getUser() {
       ...
       return new ResponseEntity<>(user, HttpStatus.OK);
    }          
}
```

Answer (score 6):

If you decide the annotation to be [`@Inherited`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/Inherited.html), yes. In this example, `@RestController` is not defined with the `@Inherited` meta-annotation, so it is not applied to subclasess of `AbstractController`.

Comment: Suggested enhancement to answer: Specifying [`@RestController`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RestController.html) (or `@Controller` or `@Component`) will likely cause an exception, because Spring will try to instantiate the `abstract` class.

Comment: @Andreas You have to give Spring some credit. It doesn't do such things.

Answer (score 3):

There are two questions here. [SJuan76 has answered the first](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33403458/438154), concerning inheritance of type annotations.

The second question

> is a `@RestController` annotation necessary for `UserController` to register?

is a little more involved.

Spring has a concept of [meta-annotations](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-meta-annotations):

> Many of the annotations provided by Spring can be used as
>   meta-annotations in your own code. A meta-annotation is simply an
>   annotation that can be applied to another annotation.
>
> [...]
>
> Meta-annotations can also be combined to create composed annotations.
>   For example, the `@RestController` annotation from Spring MVC is
>   composed of `@Controller` and `@ResponseBody`.

However, the component scanning process will not generate a bean definition for `abstract` classes. What's more, it won't discover these meta-annotations on subtypes that aren't themselves annotated. In other words, Spring will skip over your `UserController` type and won't register a bean definition for it. (I'm sure it could, it just doesn't as of `4.1.7.RELEASE`.)

Now, if you did annotate your type `UserController` with `@Component` to force Spring to generate a bean definition, the Spring MVC process that handles `@ResponseBody` would detect the `@RestController` annotations on the `AbstractController` supertype.

This is done in [`RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.html) which uses [`AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/annotation/AnnotationUtils.html#findAnnotation-java.lang.Class-java.lang.Class-) to find an annotation on the type that contains your handler method. Its javadoc states

> Find a single `Annotation` of `annotationType` on the supplied `Class`,
>   **traversing its interfaces, annotations, and superclasses** if the
>   annotation is not present on the given class itself.
>
> This method explicitly handles class-level annotations which are not
>   declared as inherited **as well as meta-annotations** and annotations on
>   interfaces.

Therefore, if you had

```
@Component
@RequestMapping(value = "/user")
public class UserController extends AbstractController {
```

Spring would detect and generate a bean for `UserController`. When handling a request to `/user` with your `getUser` handler method, Spring MVC would operate as if your class was actually annotated with `@RestController` (or `@ResponseBody`).

However, again in your case, your handler method is returning a `ResponseEntity`. That's not handled by the `HandlerMethodReturnValueHandler` for `@ResponseBody`, it's handled by [`HttpEntityMethodProcessor`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/HttpEntityMethodProcessor.html).

---

A word of caution with `abstract` classes meant to be supertypes of `@Controller` types: if you have many subtypes also meant to be beans and the `abstract` supertype contains `@RequestMapping` annotated methods, Spring MVC will fail to register your handler methods because it will consider that supertype method to be duplicated across them.